# Using Minion's footnotefigures within KOMA-classes

Tags: fonts, footnotes, koma-script, minionpro

I really like to use the `MinionPro` package in my documents, which provides an option called `footnotefigures` that activates a special set of figures for footnotes.

Unfortunately this option is not fully compatibel with the KOMA-classes such as `scrbook` while everthing works fine for example with `article`. If `footnotefigures` is active in `scrbook`, the footnote figures in the *text* are set correctly, but not the ones in the *footnotes*, which I would like to change.

At the moment this incompatibility produces a rather poor outcome, especially when a 'high' character like 'h' follows the footnote figure – as you can see in this figure.

[image]

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[footnotefigures]{MinionPro}
\begin{document}
abc \vfill
\footnote{h -- First footnote.}h
\footnote{h -- Second footnote}h 
\footnote{h -- Third footnote}h 
\footnote{h -- Fourth footnote}h 
\end{document}
```

And here is the declaration of `footnotefigures` from the `MinionPro` package documentation.

```
\DeclareOption{footnotefigures}{%
\def\@makefnmark{%
\begingroup
\normalfont
\fontfamily{MinionPro-Extra}\fontencoding{U}\selectfont
\@thefnmark
\endgroup}}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate please, why the printout seems rather poor to you? Besides that, the guy who maintains KOMAscript has a website at www.komascript.de . You may ask there in English language, if you like.

Comment: @KeksDose In my opinion the figures of the footnotes should be placed a bit higher than the letters as you can see it for example with Computer Modern. But here the top of the '1' is below the top of 'h' in the footnote. Interestingly, with 11pt as the fontsize in `scrbook`, the footnote figures look better too.

Comment: If you look closely, it's not just the placement of the figures: they are different figures. Those in the text are (as they should be) the specially designed superior figures. The ones in the footnotes themselves are small versions of what look to me to be oldstyle figures (though it's hard to be sure): at any rate a different design (look at base of 4, eg). Presumably KOMA uses a different command to set the note mark in text and in the note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking deeper into the KOMA-classes, it seems as if adding this line to the preamble does the job.

```
\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{%
  \fontfamily{MinionPro-Extra}\fontencoding{U}\selectfont\thefootnotemark}
```

Now the number of the footnotes share the same style in the text and in the footnotes.

Comment: I integrated this fix into the newest versions of [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) for MinionPro, MyriadPro and CronosPro. Thanks for fixing!

Comment: Wouldn't have `\addtokomafont{footnote}{<specs>}` have sufficed?